# Python "expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions,but got array with shape .." problem

Tags: python

write a python program, use 1D convolutional meural network to predict a series of data (regression), the program is as follows:

```
# normalize the Dataset
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(cnn_tube_par_X_train)
sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test = sc_X.transform(cnn_tube_par_X_test)
sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(cnn_tube_eff_Y_train)
sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_test = sc_Y.transform(cnn_tube_eff_Y_test)
print(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train.shape)
print(sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train.shape)


# 1D convolutional neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,padding='valid',activation='relu',input_shape=(109,5)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,padding='valid',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['mse','mae'])

model.fit(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train,sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train,epochs=5000,verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train)
```

But it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/win/PycharmProjects/allGlassStraightThroughTube/cnnTest.py", line 83, in <module>
    model.fit(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train,sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train,epochs=5000,verbose=1)
  ...
  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (109, 5)
```

the sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train.shape is (109,5)
the sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train.shape is(109,1)

it seems that the needed input in the

```
model.fit(.....)
```

should be a 3 dimension, but my input is a (109,5) array, could you please tell me the reason and how to correct it
and in the program,

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,padding='valid',activation='relu',input_shape=(109,5)))
```

in this sentence, I set the "input_shape = (109,5)",is it right

Answer (score 0):

If it wants a 3D array, give it a 3D array! Try this and let me know if it works.

```
x1=sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train
x1=x1.reshape([x1.shape[0],x1.shape[1],1])
x2=sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train
x2=x2.reshape([x2.shape[0],x2.shape[1],1])

model.fit(x1,x2,epochs=5000,verbose=1)
```

Assuming 109 is the number of data points, your input shape would be (1,5,1) or (1,5) whichever works.

Comment: imodel.add(Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,padding='valid',activation='relu',input_shape=(109,5)))；；；in this sentence, I set the "input_shape = (109,5)",is it right，thank you